# Execute trigger/task only once in Spring-boot and de-register task during runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-scheduled

I'm Integrating payment module in our application using spring boot. I'm stuck with one of the edge cases where user close the browser during transaction.

As user close the browser I need to update my transaction table with status failed. But unfortunately I can't as the url is of the merchant site. So I thought of writing a trigger ( using Spring boot ) when an entry goes in transaction table (Hibernate).

The trigger should update the transaction status after timeout (30 min approx) if the user closes the browser while doing payment.

Incase if the transaction is either success of failure then I do not want to execute the trigger.

I couldn't figure out how to do that in Spring-boot so I used plain Java timerTask which will be executed only once after 30  min. Is there a better approach using spring boot?

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LOGGER.info("Trigger for Transaction id "+transactionId);
                }
            }, 
            1000 * 60 * 30 // 30 mins
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you might approach this from the wrong angle.
You're considering having the closing be the problem of the transaction.

Why not consider dangling transactions as a whole? Have a single job, which runs every minute, and closes overly long transactions?

That way, you can ensure that *all* transactions are ended within a certain amount of time.

Comment: So every min job will hit the DB to check if transaction status is null or no and transaction time > 30 mins

Comment: That is what I would do... Index the transaction status and the time, so it'll be an effortless query.